# Adding dictionaries to Plist programmatically

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, plist

I am trying to add a dictionary to a plist programmatically in the following format:

Root(Dict)
|
StringOfViewID(Dict)
|
ButtonTitle(Dict)
|
String
String

I can successfully do this but I want to keep adding to the ViewID(Dict) more ButtonTitle(Dict) under the same ViewID(Dict).

So far I can only replace the existing.

Something like this:

Root(Dict)
|
StringOfViewID(Dict) - ButtonTitle(Dict)(2)-String String
|
ButtonTitle(Dict)(1)
|
String
String

Here is the code I'm using:

```
//Initialize and load the plist file here: 
[...]
            NSMutableDictionary *data;
            NSMutableDictionary *viewID;
            NSMutableDictionary *buttonName;
            NSArray *keys;
            NSArray *locations;


        // Insert the data into the plist

        NSNumber *xNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:locationX];
        NSNumber *yNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:locationY];

        keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"locationX", @"locationY", nil];
        locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:xNumber, yNumber, nil];
        data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:locations forKeys:keys];
        buttonName = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:data forKey:myButtonTitle];
        viewID = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:buttonName forKey:@"StringOfViewID"];

        [viewID writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand your data structure.  I think you have one too many dictionaries.  It looks like you can just keep adding `buttonName` dictionary entries to this root dictionary and you don't need the "StringOfViewID" dictionary.

Comment: I actually need all dictionaries. I'm getting the ID of the view (i.e. tag) so it is a different dictionary that will hold many buttons on each view and each button need to have it's coordinates and name. At least this makes sense to me but if you can propose a better way do let please do as I am a bit lost....

Comment: Do you want to add more buttons after you have read the plist file back in to memory or just the first time when you create the file?

Comment: No I want to add more buttons after I write the plist. Different go every view. Some views may have no buttons and some maybe added by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class to serve as a data model.  This is a simple implementation - it would probably be cleaner to create a `Button` object rather than pass multiple parameters and retrieve a dictionary

*ViewButtons.h*

```
@interface ViewButtons : NSObject

+(ViewButtons *) viewButtonsWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)file;

-(void) addButton:(NSString *)buttonName withX:(double) x andY:(double) y toView:(NSString *)viewName;
-(NSArray *)viewNames;
-(NSArray *)buttonNamesForView:(NSString *)viewName;
-(NSDictionary *)buttonWithName:(NSString *)name inView:(NSString *)viewName;
-(void)writeToFile:(NSString *)file;

@end
```

*ViewButtons.m*

```
#import "ViewButtons.h"

@interface ViewButtons ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *viewButtons;

@end

@implementation ViewButtons

-(id) init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        self.viewButtons=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
    return self;
}

+(ViewButtons *) viewButtonsWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)file {
    ViewButtons *newViewButtons=[ViewButtons alloc];
    newViewButtons.viewButtons=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file];
    return newViewButtons;
}

-(void) addButton:(NSString *)buttonName withX:(double) x andY:(double) y toView:(NSString *)viewName {
    NSMutableDictionary *viewDict=self.viewButtons[viewName];
    if (viewDict == nil) {
        viewDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
        self.viewButtons[viewName]=viewDict;
    } else if (![viewDict isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
        viewDict=[viewDict mutableCopy];
        self.viewButtons[viewName]=viewDict;
    }
    NSNumber *xNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x];
    NSNumber *yNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:y];
    NSDictionary *buttonDict=@{@"locationX":xNumber,@"locationY":yNumber};
    viewDict[buttonName]=buttonDict;
}


-(NSArray *)viewNames {
    return self.viewButtons.allKeys;
}

-(NSArray *)buttonNamesForView:(NSString *)viewName {
    return [self.viewButtons[viewName] allKeys];
}
-(NSDictionary *)buttonWithName:(NSString *)name inView:(NSString *)viewName {
    return self.viewButtons[viewName][name];
}

-(void)writeToFile:(NSString *)file {
    [self.viewButtons writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

You can use this class as follows -

```
ViewButtons *viewButtons=[ViewButtons viewButtonsWithContentsOfFile:buttonFile];
if (viewButtons == nil) {
    viewButtons=[ViewButtons new];
}

[viewButtons addButton:@"MyButton1" withX:0 andY:0 toView:@"MyView"];
[viewButtons addButton:@"MyButton2" withX:1 andY:1 toView:@"MyView"];
[viewButtons addButton:@"MyButton3" withX:0 andY:0 toView:@"MySecondView"];
[viewButtons addButton:@"MyButton4" withX:0 andY:1 toView:@"MyThirdView"];
[viewButtons writeToFile:buttonFile];
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply load the file first into `NSMutableDictionary` , make the changes you want to it, then write it back to the file using the same code you use already.

Edit: Regarding the structure you use for editing the list , you can either have an array of button dictionaries

```
   NSMutableDictionary* oldDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

   // make the new button dictionary
   NSNumber *xNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:locationX];
   NSNumber *yNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:locationY];

   NSDictionary*buttonDictionary=@{@"locationX": xNumber,
                                   @"locationY":yNumber,
                                   @"myButtonTitle":myButtonTitle};
   NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [oldDictionary objectForKey:@"StringOfViewID"];
   //append it to the array
   [buttonsArray addObject:buttonDictionary];
   //replace the old array with the new one
   [oldDictionary setObject:buttonsArray forKey:@"StringOfViewID"];
   //write it back to the file
   [oldDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Or a dictionary of buttons dictionaries

```
    NSMutableDictionary* oldDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // make the new button dictionary
    NSNumber *xNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:locationX];
    NSNumber *yNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:locationY];

    NSDictionary*buttonLocationDictionary=@{@"locationX": xNumber, @"locationY":yNumber};
    NSMutableDictionary *buttonsDictionary = [oldDictionary objectForKey:@"StringOfViewID"];
    //add it to the dictionary
    [buttonsDictionary  setObject:buttonLocationDictionary forKey:myButtonTitle];//be sure that this is a new button title,or else it will replace the old value with this title.

    //replace the old dictionary with the new one
    [oldDictionary setObject:buttonsDictionary forKey:@"StringOfViewID"];
    //write it back to the file
    [oldDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

I tried to not change the structure or the keys you are using, and I assumed that `StringOfViewID` is the key that all the buttons in the current view of interest will have, and other views will have other keys.

Comment: I've tried to copy it and then do this:  [viewID copy];
newViewID = [NSMutableDictionary mutableCopy];
but I get a crash.

Comment: then I tried this:   NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryWithExistingKey = [viewID objectForKey:@"StringOfViewID"];
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryOldAndNewItems = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionaryWithExistingKey];
[dictionaryOldAndNewItems addEntriesFromDictionary:buttonName];
[newViewID setObject:dictionaryOldAndNewItems forKey:@"StringOfViewID"];
[newViewID writeToFile:path atomically:YES];but nothing is happening

Comment: `addEntriesFromDictionary` will replace the old value with the new value as long as you use the same key. You need to insert the new `buttonName` with a new key, or make it an array of buttonNames under the same key. I can provide you with example code if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: it would be appreciated... I tried this:   NSMutableDictionary *existingDictionary;
[existingDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:viewID];  NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryOldAndNewItems = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:existingDictionary];
        [dictionaryOldAndNewItems addEntriesFromDictionary:buttonName];
        [newViewID setObject:dictionaryOldAndNewItems forKey:@"StringOfViewID"];
        
        [newViewID writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        
without success

Comment: @GeorgeAsda I have added code for both ways, check them and tell me if anything isn't clear or if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: As I can't test it now, you may face an issue because of mutability, if so you can use this for reading: NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path  options: 0 error: &error;];
    if (data == nil) {
        NSLog (@"error reading %@: %@", path, error);
        return nil;
    }
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSMutableDictionary *oldDic = (NSMutableDictionary*)[NSPropertyListSerialization  propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                        format:&format
                        errorDescription:&error];

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem I'm facing is that when I first initialize the plist file it is an empty one. So the "StringOfViewID" dictionary is not there. and i get: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: StringOfViewID)'. SO I need to create it first and then try to edit it by adding buttons... what is the best way to do this? Thanks