# Appending Data to .plist file programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, plist

I am using a pList named `name.plist`. I am trying to add New Names value in plist but none of the methods is go through work for me.
[image]
what i am trying:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

{
NSMutableArray *plist_names;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];


NSArray *folder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString *dir = [folder objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"name.plist"]];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]==NO)
{
   plist_names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
else
{
     plist_names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}


//NSLog(@"%@",[plist_names objectAtIndex:0]);  //App Crashes

NSLog(@"%@",plist_names);  //Blank Console





}
@end
```

I can't figure out what i am missing. I am working on Xcode6 and developing for ios8.

Questions Viewed:
[Adding dictionaries to Plist programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640424/adding-dictionaries-to-plist-programmatically)
[Appending data to PLIST - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884215/appending-data-to-plist-iphone)
and many more

Comment: I think you can not add any value/data  in .plist file programmatically. you can do only by manually. But you can fetch data from .plist file and store them to NSDic/Array and then after you can modify it.

Comment: @Romance I searched over net and found many ways to add. But when i start doing that i doesn't work for me

Comment: No, you can not change any thing in the bundle by programmatically.

Comment: Didn't you know that NSUserDefaults is a plist?

Comment: i didn't get what are you talking about ? @BogdanMatveev

Comment: You can store your data in NSUserDefaults locally, and you can easily  manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write files to the application bundle but really you shouldn't to do this. You'll break code signing, and your app will no longer start. You should use the established conventions such as writing to Library or Documents folder of your app. Look at this SO for how: [Get file path by file name from documents directory ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780928/get-file-path-by-file-name-from-documents-directory-ios)

Comment: what should i do ? will i have to make a copy of plist file to Documents Directory

Comment: How can i achieve this

Comment: It's similar to the code you posted above, but with a different path. Try it, see if it works, and if not post code as to why

Comment: I updated my question with the new code but still i am not getting  the output.  @GaryRiches

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it::

First open AppDelegate.m and In DidFinishLoading Section Write this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

NSArray *folder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString *dir = [folder objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path =[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"name.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]==NO)
{
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:path error:nil];
}

return YES;
}
```

> Now ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *folder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString *dir = [folder objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"name.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *plist_names = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableArray *names = [plist_names objectForKey:@"Names"];

NSLog(@"%@",[names objectAtIndex:1]);

[names addObject:@"jkl"];

NSLog(@"%@",[names objectAtIndex:2]);

 [ plist_names setObject:names forKey:@"Names"];


[plist_names writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```